# print spaces with String.format()

Tags: java, string, format

how I can rewrite this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSpaces; i++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

using `String.format()`?

*PS*

I'm pretty sure that this is possible but the [javadoc is a bit confusing](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Comment: I dont think questions get the credit they deserve so upvoting!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need to specify the minimum width of the field.

```
String.format("%" + numberOfSpaces + "s", "");
```

Why do you want to generate a String of spaces of a certain length.

If you want a column of this length with values then you can do:

```
String.format("%" + numberOfSpaces + "s", "Hello");
```

which gives you numberOfSpaces-5 spaces followed by Hello. If you want Hello to appear on the left then add a minus sign in before numberOfSpaces.

Comment: in C I would write: printf("%.*s", numberOfSpacs, " "); without any string concatenation

Comment: Or, if you're feeling saucy, String.format(String.format("%%%ds", numberOfSpaces), "")

Comment: I know this is totally old but: is this possible for leading AND trailing spaces? I knwo that you use the "-" sign for trailing but I don't know if it's possible to combine them

Answer (score 18):

```
int numberOfSpaces = 3;
String space = String.format("%"+ numberOfSpaces +"s", " ");
```