# Printf in Java with variable spaces

Tags: java, eclipse, printing

I have a problem with printf in java. I would like to define the spaces with a variable.

```
    String a = "bar";
    String b ="foo";

     System.out.printf("%-10s %s", b, a);
```

//Output:foo*7spaces*bar

The "10" should be changeable. I hope you know what I mean. Thank you guys!

Comment: Have a look at this answer: [print spaces with String.format()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1073803/412712).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int length = 10;
System.out.printf("%-" + length + "s %s", b, a);
```

Comment: Ohh thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "bar";
String b ="foo";
int numspace = 10;
String space = String.format("%"+ numspace +"s", " ");

     System.out.printf("%s %s %s", b,space, a);
```

Comment: @KarleMari i hope this is what you mean